# array in function outputs nothing

Tags: php

When I am trying to add values to an array it just output array for me,

```
function getAllRoles($format='ids')
{   
$format = strtolower($format);
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM roles");
    $query->execute();
    $resp = array();
foreach ($query as $row){
    if ($format == 'full'){
        $resp[] = array("ID"=>$row['ID'],"Name"=>$row['roleName']);
    }else{
        $resp[] = $row['ID'];
    }
}
return $resp;
}
```

To get the array I typed,

```
echo "<br>getAllRoles: ".$Secure->getAllRoles("full");
```

Comment: Not `echo` to print an array hou have to use `print_r($array)` or `var_dump($array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the string concatenation operator, so all parameters will be converted to strings.
An array converted to a string displays as `Array`.

What do you expect the output to be?

You have to loop over the array in order to output each element. In your case, you have a "fixed" array anyway (the datastructure won't change and you always know the number of elements in there):

```
$data = $Secure->getAllRoles("full");
echo $data['ID'];
echo $data['Name'];
```

Comment: I expect it to be like ID=>1,Name=>Admin

Comment: @8803286 Then use `print_r($data)` or `var_dump($data)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can't perform an `echo` on an array. `echo` expects the parameter to be `string`.
what you can do is to loop over the array and print/echo all the indexes like:

```
foreach($arrayname as $something)
{
echo $something;
}
```

which will print out each index.
if you tried to echo an array you will get `Array` as an output.
read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting array:-

Your function returning this array:-

```
$resp=array("ID"=>$row['ID'],"Name"=>$row['roleName']);
```

If you want to echo all element in array then you have to mentions its key.

You can achieve this:-

```
 $allRoles = $Secure->getAllRoles("full");

 echo "<br>getAllRoles: ".$allRoles['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($format == 'full'){
  $resp=array("ID"=>$row['ID'],"Name"=>$row['roleName']);
}else{
  $resp = $row['ID'];
}
```

To

```
if ($format == 'full'){
  $resp[]=array("ID"=>$row['ID'],"Name"=>$row['roleName']);
}else{
  $resp[] = $row['ID'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not `echo` to print an array you have to use `print_r($array)` or `var_dump($array)` or `foreach`

Don't use

```
echo $Secure->getAllRoles("full");
```

Use:

```
print_r($Secure->getAllRoles("full"));

or

var_dump($Secure->getAllRoles("full"));

or

$resp = $Secure->getAllRoles("full");
foreach($resp as $key=>$value) {
    echo "$key = $value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can to use echo to output the array. You may use a `var_dump` or a `print_r` to get the details of the array.

```
var_dump($array);
print_r($array);
```

or if you still need to go for an echo then use a `json_encode` to convert to json string like

```
echo json_encode($array);
```